# Unittest error 'issubclass arg 2'

Tags: python

I am not sure what the meaning of this error is.
This is my test:

```
def test_method_delete(self):
        test_graph = trie_builder.Graph()
        node_name = 'node_0'
        test_graph.node(node_name)
        # Create a node.

        test_graph.delete(node_name)
        # Delete the node.
        self.assertNotIn(node_name, test_graph.node_list)
        node_name = 'node_1'
        with self.assertRaises(KeyError('ERROR: Attempt to delete non-existent node.')):
            test_graph.delete(node_name)
```

This is my method:

```
def delete(self, node_name):
        if node_name in self.node_list:
            del self.node_list[node_name]
        else:
            raise(KeyError('ERROR: Attempt to delete non-existent node.'))
```

And this is the error:

```
ERROR: test_method_delete (__main__.test_class_Graph)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_trie_builder.py", line 66, in test_method_delete
    test_graph.delete(node_name)
  File "/Users/juliushamilton/Documents/Work/Nantomics_trie_builder/trie_builder/trie_builder.py", line 25, in delete
    raise(KeyError('ERROR: Attempt to delete non-existent node.'))
KeyError: 'ERROR: Attempt to delete non-existent node.'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_trie_builder.py", line 66, in test_method_delete
    test_graph.delete(node_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 184, in __exit__
    if not issubclass(exc_type, self.expected):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes
```

What could be the problem? What is 'arg2' referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried passing the `KeyError` class (without instantiating an instance) to `assertRaises`? It looks like `assertRaises` is trying to check that the error it got is of the type of error class you gave it, but `KeyError('ERROR: Attempt to delete non-existent node.')` is an instance of type `KeyError`, not the type itself.

```
with self.assertRaises(KeyError):
    test_graph.delete(node_name)
```

It looks like the docs don't make this clear:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises, but from the stack trace your gave it looks like what it does is check that the exception it receives is a subclass of the exception class you passed to it using `issubclass`. `issubclass` can only accept a type as its second argument, so passing an instance is the error you are getting.

If you want to also check the error text you need to use `assertRaisesRegexp`:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegexp

Comment: + If you want to check for the error text, you need to use [`assertRaisesRegexp()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegexp)

Comment: @dhke added this to the post.